# I cannot customize custom widgets anymore after moving WordPress website

Tags: web-deployment, wordpress

The situation is the following one: A colleague of mine built a WordPress theme with some custom widgets which need to be configured through `/wp-admin/widgets.php`.

In the local copy that me and him have installed everything works fine (it's the latest WP, the production database and the theme from bitbucket). The production is ok, but it's impossibile to change the widgets options since every widget has a `There are no options for this widget.` label.

So I did a setup from scratch: I created a new WP-ready droplet on Digital Ocean, imported the database I have locally (1:1 production since I changed my `/etc/hosts` to point the production domain to my localhost) and cloned the theme, but still I got the same issue of production: Widgets were not customizable. Also there are no references to `localhost` in `wp_option` rows.

**tl;dr**: With the same database and the same files, the website works fine locally while in the production machine (AWS) and in the staging droplet (DO) widgets are not customizable.

Comment: Hello @Roxas shadow. You can ask this question in http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ , may be there will be more people who could help.

Comment: "There are no options for this widget means the `WP_Widget::form ` method was not overridden, please make sure it's being called. Also taking a look at these widgets might help point out the issue. Are the standard WordPress widgets working fine?

Comment: @soulseekah yes, the standard widgets work fine, while the custom made seem working fine only in local envs. Every widget is a class that extends `WP_Widget` and yes, it contains the constructor and the `form`, `update` and `widget` methods.

Comment: Roxas, you should trace the execution through to the form() method to see if they even get called, you can try callling `var_dump( debug_backtrace() ); exit;` in the form and seeing whether it even gets there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just understood what happened: The custom widgets were using short tags (`<?`) to split up the HTML output, which directive (`short_open_tag`) is disabled by default in the production environment.

Problems like this are a pain to spot and I can do nothing but laughing thinking what we tried to understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

May be there are some problems with moving to production,check this: [Moving site from development to production](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/109814/moving-site-from-development-to-production) , and this: [How to migrate subsite from dev multisite to production multisite](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/131934/how-to-migrate-subsite-from-dev-multisite-to-production-multisite) , hope these will help.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I just tried, as the first link suggested, to import everything but the `wp_options`, so I generated this one from a clean installation of WordPress, but nothing was solved. The second link refers to a multisite blog, that's not my case.